# Exporting object keys individually

Tags: javascript, typescript, vitest

I want to mock `fs` in vitest using [memfs](https://github.com/streamich/memfs). And for that I created a mock file  `./__mocks__/fs.ts` and set up the mocked volume and fs.

However, I cannot get the mocked export to work properly. I always get `TypeError: readdirSync is not a function`.

What is the correct way to export this?

`__mocks_/fs.ts`:

```
// fs.ts
import { createFsFromVolume, Volume } from "memfs"

const musicFolder = "./musicFolder"
const files = {
  "./1.mp3": "1",
  "./2.mp3": "2",
}

const volume = Volume.fromJSON(files, musicFolder)

const fs = createFsFromVolume(volume)

export { fs } // This does not work
```

`Test file`:

```
// test.spec.ts
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from "vitest"
import * as fs from "fs"

vi.mock("fs")

it("testing fs", async () => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync("./musicFolder") //! TypeError: readdirSync is not a function

  expect(files).toBeTruthy()
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into the problem of [importing an entire module's contents under a namespace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_entire_modules_contents) and the requirement to explicitly define each export by name. Using ES modules, there's no way around this.

IMO, part of the problem is that you are utilizing mixed implicit behavior provided by `vitest`, and explicit behavior in your code. It's easier for me to reason about code when it is explicit. Consider this alternative to the `vi.mock` method:

For this example, let's say that the module you're testing is at `./src/example.ts`.

### Mock module

Create a mock module alongside your test module (which I'll describe next):

> I'm using the convention of `[name].test.mock.[ext]`

```ts
// ./src/example.test.mock.ts

import { createFsFromVolume, type IFs, Volume } from 'memfs';

// A factory to produce the mocked fs
export function createFs (): IFs {
  const files = {
    './1.mp3': '1',
    './2.mp3': '2',
  };

  const dir = './musicFolder';
  const volume = Volume.fromJSON(files, dir);
  return createFsFromVolume(volume);
}

// Or export an instance of it directly
// if it's the only one that you actually need
export const fs = createFs();
```

### Test module

> I'm using the convention of `[name].test.[ext]`

Here are two ways you can write it:

**First version**

```ts
// ./src/example.test.ts

import { expect, it } from 'vitest';

// If the real `fs` from Node is needed elsewhere in your test,
// then keep this import.
import * as fs from 'node:fs';

import { createFs } from './example.test.mock.js';

it('testing fs', async () => {
  const fs = createFs();
  const files = fs.readdirSync('./musicFolder');
  expect(files).toBeTruthy();
});

// Use the real `fs` in other tests...
```

**Second version**

If you don't need the real `fs` in your test, then just use the mocked version directly:

```ts
// ./src/example.test.ts

import { expect, it } from 'vitest';
import { fs } from './example.test.mock.js';

it('testing fs', async () => {
  const files = fs.readdirSync('./musicFolder');
  expect(files).toBeTruthy();
});
```

### Summary

Both of those versions of the test run without error and pass:

```
so-72860426 % node --version
v16.15.1

so-72860426 % npm run test

> so-72860426@0.1.0 test
> vitest


 DEV  v0.17.0 /stack-overflow/so-72860426

 ✓ src/example.test.ts (1)

Test Files  1 passed (1)
     Tests  1 passed (1)
      Time  906ms (in thread 34ms, 2666.13%)


 PASS  Waiting for file changes...
       press h to show help, press q to quit
```

And here are my repo config files so that you can reproduce this:

`./package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "so-72860426",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "vitest"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4",
    "vitest": "^0.17.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "memfs": "^3.4.7"
  }
}
```

`./tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "lib": [
      "esnext"
    ],
    // "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "nodenext",
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer! There is one problem though: I am using `vi.mock` here as I am going to import other functions which I want to test. And those call `fs`. `vi.mock` will make sure that they will use the mocked version of `fs`. It will also mock the imports inside the file. It is quite practical, but a bit weird, as it gets hoisted (which is where its power comes from). So I will just export the single function from fs which I use (I just use like three anyway)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a default export as mentioned in https://vitest.dev/api/#vi-mock.

`__mocks_/fs.ts`:

```js
import { createFsFromVolume, Volume } from "memfs"

const musicFolder = "./musicFolder"
const files = {
  "./1.mp3": "1",
  "./2.mp3": "2",
}

const volume = Volume.fromJSON(files, musicFolder)

const fs = createFsFromVolume(volume)

export default fs
```

You have to be a bit careful when running multiple tests that expect a new volume each time.

The best way I have found so far is to use a dynamic import and reset the module before each test as mentioned in https://vitest.dev/api/#vi-resetmodules:

```js
import { describe, expect, it, vi } from "vitest"

vi.mock("fs")

beforeEach(() => {
  vi.resetModules()
})

it("testing fs", async () => {
  const fs = (await import("fs")).default

  const files = fs.readdirSync("./musicFolder")

  expect(files).toBeTruthy()
})
```